# Need a linebreak in text while converting html to txt

Tags: xslt

I am using xslt to converting html to a text file. When I view it in notepad, the content is shown as a single line.

What shall I make it to display like a paragraph. What should be included in template match p, after taking content from p tag to make the next p tag content to display in next line?

Comment: Try notepad++ rather than using normal notepad

Comment: you want this thing to be done manually after converting into text pad or you wanna code fr it so it will generate CLEAN File fr u !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To generate a line break in xslt you can do:

```
<xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
```

then the Linebreak between the tags should transfer to your textfile.